# Will Ubuntu work on MSI GE40?

Tags: installation, nvidia, laptop, uefi, msi

I am going to buy a new laptop and I am thinking about MSI GE40 2OL-276 because of it's power and relatively low weight. But at the same time I am going to use it with Ubuntu. There are not too many posts about there "interaction" on Google, just a few with installation problems (UEFI-related) or optimus, but they seem to be solvable. So, the question is: does anyone have any experience or knowledge about using Ubuntu (or at least any linux) on this laptop? If yes, what to expect of it?

PS

Asked the same question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/682144/will-ubuntu-work-on-msi-ge40), but no replies there...

Comment: I am asking myself the same question... Did you manage to get an answer? thks

Comment: Yep! I will post a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a guy from Russian Ubuntu forum found some reassuring comments in German on the German Ubuntu forum, so I went "all in" and bought it. And it works perfectly!
There were some issues with installation because of UEFI and with Nvidia videocard, but I solved them all quite easily with use of some standard manuals on those topics.
The only issue I couldn't solve was installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, so I had to switch to classic mode in BIOS. I haven't tried to boot into preinstalled Windows after installing Ubuntu, but I believe it should work, if I switch back to UEFI.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you got this to work?

Comment: @MatthewSanders What exactly are you interested in?

Comment: well... I'm in the process of trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my MSI GS40.  I installed 32GB Ram, upgraded the M.2 SSD with a Samsung 950 PRO and replaced the 7200 drive with a Samsung 850 Pro SSD.  I may have FINALLY got it to install after several attempts, but at the time of my previous post I was only able to boot into the live USB.  If you have any specific instructions on your install I'm sure that would be helpful to others.  Thanks!

Comment: looks like I can't shutdown currently... "NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s!"

Comment: Well, as I said, for me it basically just works if I install it in legacy mode with "properly" switched off Windows.